# TCP/IP configuration using Spring framework In java

Tags: java, spring, sockets, tcp, spring-integration

I am trying to make a server socket using Spring TCP/IP integration. But the problem is, I am quiet new using Spring and the solution I found after googling couldn't help me much. I visited Spring website, they talk about a lot of things I couldn't understand. So if anybody can help me please with the Spring configuration and corresponding java code....

BTW, I am receiving a stream of bytes from the client.

Comment: To do stuff with TCP/IP I'd suggest looking at Netty w/ Spring: http://nerdronix.blogspot.com/2013/06/netty-4-configuration-using-spring-maven.html

Answer (score 3):

See the [Spring Integration Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html); pay particular attention to the discussion about using deserializers to extract messages from the stream.

Also the the [tcp-client-server, tcp-amqp, and tcp-client-server-multiplex samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples).

Comment: Thanks @Gary Russel. I have already gone through those docs. Anyway, I will give more time on those.